# Wordpress Previews When Using Gatsby and Gatsby Cloud

Tags: wordpress, gatsby, gatsby-cloud

I am building a Gatsby site(hosted with Gatsby Cloud) and using Wordpress as the CMS(https://interiordetailsgatsbywpmain.gatsbyjs.io/). The issue I am having is with the previews in Wordpress. I have GatsbyJS plugin installed and populated with the Gatsby Content Sync URL. When I go to a page, make a change and click preview it either shows the preview page without the change or it goes straight to a html render page. I don't have any errors that match this error when the site builds though. Also I am using Advanced Custom Fields on these pages.

The repo is found at https://github.com/InteriorDetails/Interior-Details-Gatsby-WP and here are some screenshots of what I am experiencing. Please let me know if more info is needed.

My client really wants these previews so any help would be really appreciated!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjiaq.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbZQp.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hy3M.png

Comment: I am glad nobody is experiencing this issue, but was hoping one person may have an idea why this is happening :)

Comment: Just asking one more time if anyone has any ideas why my previews may not be working?